# matplotlib - Disappearing curve when axis not displayed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I encountered this peculiar behavior when plotting with matplotlib:

```
mean = 0
variance = np.linspace(0.5, 1, 3)
x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
for var in variance:
  plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x,mean,np.sqrt(var)))
  #plt.axes(frameon = False)
```

This outputs the expected result :

[image: with frame]

However, once I uncomment,

```
mean = 0
variance = np.linspace(0.5, 1, 3)
x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
for var in variance:
   plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x,mean,np.sqrt(var)))
   plt.axes(frameon = False)
```

I get this :

[image: without frame]

Why is the curve disappearing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `plt.axes` is doing surprising things with global state.  The first call to `plt.plot` is creating a new `Axes`, the call to `plt.axes` is then creating a *new* `Axes`, the second call to `plt.plot` plots to the new Axes and then the call to `plt.axes` returns the *same* `Axes` object as the last time it was called (because it keeps track of what a 'signature' for the axes and does not re-create it if it does not have to), and then the third `plt.plot` plots to the same axes as the second call to `plt.plot`.

To fix up your code

```
from matplotlib import mlab
import numpy as np

mean = 0
variance = np.linspace(0.5, 1, 3)
x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
plt.axes(frameon = False) 
for var in variance:
   plt.plot(x, mlab.normpdf(x,mean,np.sqrt(var)))
```

But it is better do to

```
from matplotlib import mlab
import numpy as np

mean = 0
variance = np.linspace(0.5, 1, 3)
x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_frame_on(False)
for var in variance:
   ax.plot(x, mlab.normpdf(x,mean,np.sqrt(var)))
```

Comment: That explains it, yes. However, is it right to call this a bug ?

Comment: I think this is correct but annoying behavior. The OO style is preferred anyway.